# Map many possible input values to discrete color domains

Tags: d3.js

I can't grok the docs on d3's [ordinal scales](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#ordinal-scales). The way I read it (and the way it works for linear scales, I feel I should be able to proceed like this:

```
color = d3.scale.ordinal();
color.domain([0, 100]);      // Input is any percentage point 0-100
color.range([                // Output is a scale of colors from "bad" to "good"
  'red','orange','blue','green'
]);
```

This doesn't give me the results I expect:

```
color(0); // "red". Ok, that makes sense
color(1); // "blue". Huh? This should be "red"
color(100); // "orange". Really? I'm confused. What's the range?
color.range(); //["red", "orange", "blue", "green"]. That looks right...
color.domain(); // [0,1,100]. Um...
```

It looks like it's treating inputs as discrete categorical values when I want to treat them like numbers.

Comment: Well that's what the ordinal scales do -- see the docs. In particular you should have one domain element per range element. You probably want a linear scale instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct approach for mapping a range of numbers to discrete outputs is to use [`quantize`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales). The difference wasn't clear to me and ordinal seemed intuitive. Figured it out now.

A working solution looks like this:

```
color = d3.scale.quantize();
color.domain([0, 100]);
color.range([
  'red','orange','blue','green'
]);

color(0);  // "red"
color(1);  // "red"
color(99); // "green"
```

These links here helpful in figuring this out:

- http://roadtolarissa.com/blog/2015/01/04/coloring-maps-with-d3/
- [What is the difference between d3.scale.quantize() and d3.scale.quantile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258996/what-is-the-difference-between-d3-scale-quantize-and-d3-scale-quantile)

Answer (score 2):

The approach to this is not exactly how it works. The domain you listed will point to 2 specific values in the range, the 2 first values - red and orange. Any other value that you add to the domain via `color(n);` will extend the domain array, eg. 1 is considered the 3rd index, therefore it is assigned the 3rd item in the range, if you were to call another item with `color(n)` you would get the 4th index. That is how the range method works.