# D3 quantize color scale not showing the right color distribution

Tags: javascript, d3.js, quantization

I'm trying to figure out how to get the right color palette given a dataset with the possibility of a wide range of values. (think github's contribution heat map)

Note that the values are dynamic so I'm not sure I can use `d3.scale.threshold`.

Quantize dataset:

```
var arr = [26,12,7,6,5,5,5,4,4,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0];
```

I'm using the following color scale, however, out of the 41 elements that should be colored, only the first four have a color, everything else is set as #eeeeee (grey).

```
    var color_scale = d3.scale.quantize()
        .domain([0, d3.max(arr)])
        .range(["#eeeeee","#edf8e9","#bae4b3","#74c476","#238b45"]);
```

**Quantize Output:**

```
color_scale(26): #238b45
color_scale(12): #bae4b3
color_scale(7) : #edf8e9
color_scale(6) : #edf8e9
color_scale(5) : #eeeeee
color_scale(4) : #eeeeee
color_scale(2) : #eeeeee
color_scale(1) : #eeeeee
color_scale(0) : #eeeeee
```

---

Update:

It appears that using quantile, does not work as expected for the following set:

Quantile dataset:

```
var arr = [26,12,7,6,5,5,5,4,4,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

Using the following color scale:

```
var color_scale = d3.scale.quantile()
    .domain(arr)
    .range(["#eeeeee","#edf8e9","#bae4b3","#74c476","#238b45"]);
```

**Quantile Output:**

```
color_scale(26): #238b45
color_scale(12): #238b45
color_scale(7) : #238b45
color_scale(6) : #238b45
color_scale(5) : #238b45
color_scale(4) : #238b45
color_scale(2) : #238b45
color_scale(1) : #74c476
color_scale(0) : #edf8e9
```

I expect all values > 0 have a color, all 0s be #eeeeee.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The quantize scale divides the domain into equal-sized chunks whose number depends on the range. In your case, you have 5 values, so the domain is divided into chunks of size 26/5 = 5.2. The first chunk (grey) includes everything up to and including 5, which is what you see in the output.

It sounds like a quantile scale would be more suitable for what you're trying to do, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258996/what-is-the-difference-between-d3-scale-quantize-and-d3-scale-quantile).

Comment: That's a good point. However, I'm not sure quantile would give the correct output as well (please see my updated question). 

It looks like quantile would not take the values into account but only the size of the dataset to create the amount of buckets and distribute them evenly.

Comment: So what do you actually want?

Comment: I expect all values > 0 have a color, all 0s be #eeeeee. If you see the [Github's](https://github.com/Ocramius) contribution heat map, all of them have a color as long as it has a number (regardless the there's a large range of values).

Comment: So use a linear scale?