# D3 Color Scale confusion in mapping continuous input to predetermined discrete bins?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors

So I am trying to create a color scale with `d3`, but I'm just confused on what scale to use exactly. I'm coloring things based off [pearson correlation](http://www.statisticshowto.com/what-is-the-pearson-correlation-coefficient/) and would like the following bins:

```
[-1,-0.5,-0.3,0,0.3,0.5,1]
```

Pearson correlation is continuous from `-1` to `1`, but the different values can mean higher correlations. For example:

high correlation: `[-1,-.5] & [.5,1]`

moderate correlation: `[-.5,-.3] & [.3,.5]`

low correlation: `[-.3,0] & [0,.3]`

I'm trying to make a [diverging](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=diverging&scheme=BrBG&n=3) color scale with the following colors:

```
colors = ["#a6611a", "#dfc27d", "#f5f5f5", "#80cdc1", "#018571"]
```

Basically, for each level of correlation, I want it to be mapped to one of those exact colors. So, high correlations would be mapped to `#a6611a` and `#018571`, moderate ones would get mapped to `#dfc27d` and `#80cdc1`, and so on. I pretty much want:

```
continuous input => discrete output
```

But I'm confused on how to do this with d3 color scales.... I know there are the quantize and quantile scales as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258996/what-is-the-difference-between-d3-scale-quantize-and-d3-scale-quantile?rq=1) but I dont know if that's what I'm looking fo.

My understanding of those is that they take in a continuous input and split the domain into either uniform segments (quantize) or by domain quantiles... however thats not what I want. I want to put in a range from `[-1,1]` and *always* get `#a6611a` and `#018571` for input in `[-1,-.5] & [.5,1]` and so on. Is this possible to do with either of those scales?

I tried:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
                      .domain([-1,-0.5,-0.3,0,0.3,0.5,1])
                      .range(colors);
```

But if I do that, I end up with `colorScale(.29) = #80cdc1` when I want `colorScale(.29) = "#f5f5f5"`.

I also tried a linear scale:

```
var colorScaleLinear = d3.scale.linear()
                      .domain([-1,-0.5,-0.3,0,0.3,0.5,1])
                      .range(colors);
```

But in that case, I will get my data mapped to colors that don't necessarily have to be one of my 5 colors. Example: `colorScaleLinear(.29) = #058774`

I'm just confused if there is a way to do this in d3, and I'm new to color scales so after spending hours on this I'm just not sure what to try... what color scale should I be using? Is there a way to set the output to be a discrete set of colors?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

**EDIT** Would [threshold](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#threshold-scales) scales be the way to go?

Comment: Yes, you have to use a threshold scale, but the domain should have less elements than the range.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Is there any reason why the domain needs to have less values?

Comment: That's pure math: If the number of values in the scale’s range is N+1, the number of values in the scale’s domain must be N. You have 5 colors, right? So, you should have 4 values in the domain, let's say A, B, C and D. Less than A, first color, Between A and B, second color, between B and C, third color, between C and D, forth color, more than D, fifth color. Did you get it?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes, makes sense thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use d3.scale.threshold().

```js
var q=d3.scale.threshold()
 .domain([-1,-0.499999,-0.2999999,0.3,0.5,1])
 .range( ["#a6611a","#a6611a", "#dfc27d", "#f5f5f5", "#80cdc1", "#018571","#018571"]);


a=[-0.5,-0.50001,-0.4999,-0.3,-0.2999,0,0.299,0.3001,0.5001,1];
a.forEach(function(i){
  console.log(i, q(i));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

```
var q=d3.scale.threshold()
.domain([-1,-0.499999,-0.2999999,0.3,0.5,1])
.range( ["#a6611a","#a6611a", "#dfc27d", "#f5f5f5", "#80cdc1", "#018571","#018571"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I dont think this is what I'm looking for. For example, I want `q(.29) = #f5f5f5`, but in this case it would map to `#80cdc1` ? I don't want equally sized bins, I want to be able to decide what my bins are if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I glossed over the bit about pearson correlation. I understand.

Comment: @ocean800 I've changed the answer to use threshold. On testing It seems to do what you need

Comment: I didn't think of just setting the first and last colors to just the same colors and was having issues on q(1)... cleared it up, thanks! :)